# Rendering the Fivestar widget

Tags: 7, rating

I am trying to render the Fivestrar widget programmatically. I have tried the following code, without success:

```
$settings = array(
  'content_type' => 'parce',
  'content_id' => $nid,
  'stars' => 5,
  'autosubmit' => TRUE,
  'allow_clear' => FALSE,
  'required' => FALSE,
  'tag' => 'vote'
);

print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('fivestar_custom_widget', $field_rating['0'], $settings));
```

I do get the widget form to print, but on submission the votes don't register; plus in this way I do not have the vote summary.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a node template you can use the following code.

```php
print render($content['field_vote']);
```

#### Reference

- [Display fivestar in template (node--***.tpl.php)](http://drupal.org/node/1114726)

Comment: Thanks, but in that case it s not in the node template but i think i am just going to preprocess the page to pass that content variable to my block. Though i wish i could have a function that would take in the rates and the nid of the node to rate to render the widget..

Comment: It's not processing the output and updating the Average with this

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add:

```
  <?php print fivestar_widget_form($node, 'name of the vote tag'); ?>
```

Just replace "name of the vote tag" with your vote tag or exclude that part if you only use the default

Comment: Thanks i tried that though `fivestar_widget_form` seems to only exist in the version 6 of the module, version 7 doen't such a fucntion therefor i get a call to "undefined function"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me,

```
   $values = array('user' => $user->uid, 'average'=>60, 'count' => 5);

   $settings = array(
    'content_type' => 'user',
    'content_id' => 2,
    'stars' => 5,
    'autosubmit' => TRUE,
    'allow_clear' => FALSE,
    'text' => 'smart', // options are none, average, smart, user, and dual
    'tag' => 'vote',
    'style' => 'dual', // options are average, dual, smart, user
    'widget' => array('name' => 'default', 'css' => 'default'),
  );

   $form['custom_five_star'] = drupal_get_form('fivestar_custom_widget', $values, $settings);
   return $form;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work on nodes and be able to submit values, you will need additional fields.

```php
$settings = array(
  'content_type' => 'profile2',
  'content_id' => $profileView->pid,
  'entity' => $profileView,
  'stars' => 5,
  'field_name' => 'field_profile_rating',
  'autosubmit' => TRUE,
  'allow_clear' => FALSE,
  'langcode' => 'und',
  'text' => 'none', // options are none, average, smart, user, and dual
  'tag' => 'vote',
  'style' => 'average', // options are average, dual, smart, user
  'widget' => array( 'name' => 'oxygen', 'css' => drupal_get_path('module', 'fivestar') . '/widgets/oxygen/oxygen.css' )
);

print render(drupal_get_form('fivestar_custom_widget', $profileView->field_profile_rating['und'][0], $settings));
```