# Rate widget won't display

Tags: 7, rating

I am trying to use the rate widget in Drupal 7, and everything looks like it should work correctly, however it isn't displaying.

I'm on one of the node types it should appear under, it does not show up.

I used to have Fivestar installed, could that be an issue?

Here's a screenshot of the nodetypes I've selected[image]

Any help would be appreciated, I can't find anything I've done wrong or that would prevent it from showing up.

Comment: did you try that on other content types?

Comment: It only seems to work on basic page

Comment: What would possibly cause this? Why would it work with one node type and not another?

Comment: Did you check the "DISPLAY SETTINGS" setting for showing the rate widget in teaser or full post and "PERMISSIONS" setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything else fails, you could create a custom block and render the rate widget programatically. This gives you more freedom anyway. Similar approaches are explained here: [Rendering the Fivestar widget](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10953/rendering-the-fivestar-widget)

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue.  Using a custom tpl.php for the node seems to fix it.

Cheers,

Comment: This does not answer the question. Could you please include details on how the template file should be customized.